# macbook pro rendering issue

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have a macbook pro early 2013 model with i7 processor and nvidia m650 graphics but when i go to the settings to enable gpu rendering there is no option to select it only cpu rendering can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: I have worked it out I needed to install the cuda add-on from nvidia for mac. once this is installed the options for cuda show up in the settings panel

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the latest Nvidia Driver for you graphics card. You can download them from  the nvidia website here: **[Mac Nvidia Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/mac-driver-archive.html)**. After you have done this you need to restart blender and the CUDA option should be available under the System Tab in you User preferences.

[image]